# Mac App Store Debug - Save page source to disk

Tags: mac, mac-appstore

I've searched the net for this, but nobody seems to have the answer. Anyone knows where the "page source" gets saved when I select Debug - Save page source to disk from within the Mac App Store? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's saved in /private/tmp as pageSource.html

Answer (score 5):

In OS X 10.9 Mavericks, it appears to save to ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.appstore/Data/Library/Documentation/pageSource.html